# Similarity of sets (considering also the set sizes)

Tags: similarity

I know that you can use the Jaccard index \ distance to measure the similarity / distance of two sets. However, I am looking for some way to scale the raw Jaccard values with respect to the lengths of the sets. For example, I want a higher similarity for two large sets with a significant overlap than for two small sets.

Of course, I could simply divide the value of the Jaccard distance by the size of the union of both sets, but is there a standard scheme of scaling for that purpose?

Comment: perhaps use the intersection size only?

Comment: Well, if one set would have the same intersection with two other sets (a large and a small one), I would rather decide for the smaller of the two other sets. Therefore, considering only the intersection will not help.

Comment: Note that the Jaccard index is size(intersection)/size(union).